# How to include an html email template in a node js application

Tags: node.js

I have an html template that we use to send to new website registrations. It is a simple html file that I would like to load into a variable so that I can replace certain parts before sending out using nodemailer (eg [FIRST_NAME]). I am trying to avoid having to paste a large chunk of html into my exports function. Any ideas on how I could go about doing that?

For a clearer idea, what I need to know is how to actually do this:

```
var first_name = 'Bob';  
var html = loadfile('abc.html').replace('[FIRST_NAME]', first_name);
```

Comment: Why not use any of the js templating engines (jade, ejs, mustache)? This is exactly the task they're made for.

Comment: Its not for client side use, I need it on the server side to send out an email. I am using Jade on the server side but I do not know how to take advantage of Jade in this specific instance.

Comment: @Mindware there's nothing stopping you from using the templating engine of your choice on the server side. It's just javascript.

Comment: Thanks @soulcheck, my issue is not the templating system but rather how to load a large amount of html into nodemailer without simply pasting it into the js page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it using ejs, but you can use any templating engine:

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var ejs = require('ejs');

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
        service: <your mail service>,
        auth: {
            user: <user>,
            pass: <password>
        }
});

function sendMail(cb) {
    var user = {firstName : 'John', lastName: 'Doe'};

    var subject = ejs.render('Hello <%= firstName %>', user);
    var text = ejs.render('Hello, <%= firstName %> <%= lastName %>!', user);


    var options = {
        from: <from>,
        replyTo: <replyto>,
        to: <to>,
        subject: subject,
        text: text
    };

    transport.sendMail(options, cb);

}
```

To load the template file just us the `fs` module. Here's how to do it synchronously when the file is encoded in utf-8:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var template = fs.readFileSync('abc.html',{encoding:'utf-8'});
```

Comment: Given the example above, how could I make it so that the text is loaded from a file where I can replace strings... eg: "var text = (loadfile('abc.html').replace('[FIRST_NAME]', first_name_variable)"

Comment: @MindWire just load it using fs module.

Comment: @MindWire remember that this is an example of synchronous loading - you can also do it asynchronously, but in case of the templates it's probably better to load them once when the application starts and store them in variables. Since node loads modules synchronously, you wouldn't gain anything from async read in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will be useful for someone, as this question is already answered.

I'm working with jade and it was quite challenging figuring it out, at the end turned out to be very simple :)

(PS: this code is not optimized, is just an example)

**Js part with nodemailer:**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
var jade = require('jade');
var config = {
  // config for sending emails like username, password, ...
}
var emailFrom = 'this@email.com';
var emailTo = 'this@email.com';
var templateDir = 'path/to/templates/';
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(config);

var username = 'thisUsername'
// rendering html template (same way can be done for subject, text)
var html = jade.renderFile(templateDir+'/html.jade', {username: 'testUsername'});

//build options
var options = {
   from: emailFrom,
    to: emailTo,
    subject: 'subject',
    html: html,
    text:'text'
};

transporter.sendMail(options, function(error, info) {
  if(error) {
    console.log('Message not sent');
    console.log(info);
    return false;
  }
  else{
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    console.log(info);
    return true;
  };
});
```

**html.jade**

```
p test email html jade
p
| Username:
| !{username}
```

Here is the example for using email-templates and nodemailer.

js file:

```
var path = require('path');
var EmailTemplate = require('email-templates').EmailTemplate;
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(config);

var templateDir = path.join(__dirname, '/yourPath/emailTemplates', 'subdir');
var template = new EmailTemplate(templateDir)
var username = 'testUsername';


var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(config)
template.render(locals, function (err, results) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err)
  }
  // replace values in html template
    console.log('template render')
    console.log(err);

    // default is results.html in this case
    // read template and replace desired values
    var res1 = results.html.toString();
    var str = res1.replace('__username__', username);
    console.log(str);
    console.log('end template render')

  transport.sendMail({
    from: emailFrom,
    to: emailTo,
    subject: 'subject',
    html: str,
    text: results.text
  }, function (err, responseStatus) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err)
    }
    console.log(responseStatus)
  })
})
```

**html.html**

```
test email html
username:

<div>
__username__
</div>
```

Comment: Giving error in line:
template.render(locals, function (err, results) {

that, locals not defined. Please help so solve this one

Comment: @RahulMankar locals should be defined by you. something like this: var locals = {
  email: 'email@example.com',
  username: 'testUsername',
  name: {
    first: 'Myfirst',
    last: 'Mylast'
  }
}
please take a look at the documentation for more https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer