# send html template in email body

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, gmail-api, email-templates

I want to implement a button which makes the user able to compose email in Gmail and in that email body, I want to send HTML email template which I already have in a separate file. how can I implement this is Nodejs or javascript? I can use https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1 to open a Gmail compose window but how to send HTML template in this link?

Comment: check this page
it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085054/how-to-include-an-html-email-template-in-a-node-js-application

Answer (score 2):

Please use [html-to-text](https://github.com/werk85/node-html-to-text) module, you can send text in html as email.

Answer (score 0):

user node mailer you can pass your template with body

> https://nodemailer.com

Comment: can I send email template in the Gmail compose window body?